# SparkJava - Route by subdomain

Tags: java, dns, spark-java

I have got one domain, lets call it mycompany.com. mycompany.com has two subdomains - a.mycompany.com and b.mycompany.com. Both resolve to the same IP. When sparkjava handles a request, is it possible to detect where the request comes from (mycompany.com or a.mycompany.com or b.mycompany.com)?

Comment: Maybe in Spark's option, we should use filters to separate different hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.host()` will show you the host of the request, regardless to the IP that it is resolved to.

Look [here](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#request) for more info